# Pressing two keys simultaneously with dragonfly

Tags: python-dragonfly

I'm trying to create a macro in Dragonfly that will press two keys simultaneously, rather than one after the other. The documentation doesn't seem to cover this. Is it possible to do this, and if so what do I call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the modifier keys (Alt, Shift, Control) like this:

```
Key("a-down, s-left, c-space")
```

Or if you're trying to combine keys with other non-modifier keys, for instance, the A key and the B key, you can do this:

```
Key("a:down, b, a:up")
```

This would likely be recognized as a simultaneous keypress by whatever program you're trying to create the command for even though it's not "truly" simultaneous.

Note that in the first example, "a-down" presses ALT then DOWN, whereas in the second example, "a:down" holds down the A key until further notice. (It is then released after the B key is pressed.)

Further details: https://dragonfly2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actions.html#basic-examples